# aws codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS CodePipeline. When trying to deploy an application using docker images and ECS services, I am getting the following error using my `buildspec.yml` file:

```
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Phase context status code: Message:
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: true
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Phase context status code: Message:
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Running command echo Logging in to Amazon ECR... Logging in to Amazon ECR...
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:36 Running command aws --version aws-cli/1.15.41 Python/2.7.6 Linux/4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.10.41
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:39 Running command $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-xxx) WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin. Login Succeeded
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:40 Running command REPOSITORY_URI= xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python: not found
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:40 Command did not exit successfully REPOSITORY_URI= xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python exit status 127
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:40 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD Success: false
[Container] 2018/08/14 06:20:40 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: REPOSITORY_URI= xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python. Reason: exit status 127
```

Any assistance is appreciated. If it helps, I can attach my `buildspec.yml` and `taskdefinition.json` files. Is there a recommended way to do that?

Comment: Exit code 127 is returned by bash when a command is not found. Most likely you do not have all of the commands used in your script installed on your image prior to running it.

Comment: so how could I check this.I  did all the needful and it is the repository Uri of the image I pushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a space between `=` and `xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python`.

This means you're evaluating `xxxx.xxxx.ecr.us-east-xxx.amazonaws.com/python` as a command, and since this URI is not a valid command, it exits with status code 127.

Simply deleting the space should help.

Comment: Thanq very much